# I have a file "F1". in between commit C1 and commit C2, file F1 is missing (It has NOT been deleted).

Tags: git

We are using Git and have a team of 4 developers.

I noticed that a file  that once existed on mainline of the project "F1" was missing from the latest commit of the mainline branch.

Running: `git log --all -- F1` returns one commit, the commit that created the file. Stepping through all the logs I have found the two commits where the file disappears. When I checkout C1 the file exists but when I checkout C2 the file is gone. These commits are linear (not the result of a merge)

Is there any known way that this can happen? If I have not provided enough information let me know, and thank you in advance.

Comment: I understand that the file was not removed in C2?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski I imagine if it had been, the `git log` command would have shown that...

Comment: What does `git show <commit-ID-of-C2> -M` tell you? Do you see file `F1` listed in the output.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Correct the file was not removed/ deleted. However it it does not appear in the commit.

Comment: @Jubobs I am not currently at work but I will try that tomorrow morning and comment.

EDIT: Actually I was using atlassian sourcetree to view all files associated with the commit and F1 was not listed. I would assume that their UI would be equivalent of git show

Comment: Did you change your .gitignore files in between C1 and C2?